# Permission denied: netcdf4 python module

Tags: python, permissions, netcdf4

I have got a big problem of using the netcdf4 python module. My error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_lmkCosmoCols.py", line 264, in <module>
    ncdf_file= netCDF4.Dataset(pathNCDF+filenameNCDF+'.nc',mode='w',format='NETCDF4')
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1875, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:13815)
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1581, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:12601)
OSError: Permission denied
```

I have installed the hdf5 library like it is described on this site:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/netcdf4-python/wikis/UbuntuInstall.wiki
and installed the netcdf4 library with this command:

```
sudo pip3 install netcdf4
```

I know I can use anaconda but I had a problem with its download an I prefer to avoid install anaconda.

I use the python3.5.2 Version. First I updated python to 3.6 but then my ubuntu (Version 16.04) got broken and I only have solved it by reinstallation of the whole system.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I think, when you start to learn python, the first thing you need to learn is virtualenv. (I also broke my OSX once)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I did not know there is something like that, Iwill check it out. I think my problem is related to the given path where the netCDF-file should be created. Is has to be an absolute one but I must have a closer look.